# Is there a better solution than my regex

Tags: regex, optimization

I've spent quit a bit trying to figure out a problem on [this website](http://regex.sketchengine.co.uk/cgi/ex1.cgi) and I eventually found an regex that worked for the what I was being asked to do

The exercise is:

```
Enter a regexp that matches all the items in the first column 
(positive examples) but none of those in the second (negative examples). 
When you press "submit", you will see what matched.

Positive    Negative
pit         pt
spot        Pot
spate       peat
slap two    part
respite
```

The answer that I found was

```
^\w?.*p[a-z ?]t\w?.*$
```

What I had found out was that all positive words had something of the form `p_t`.

I matched that with `p[a-z ?]t` and then `^\w?.*` is the match any letters preceding `p` and `\w?.*$` is to match any alphanumeric characters after `t`

What I want to know is there a better way to answer this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simpler one that matches those criteria:

```
.*p.t.*
```

This matches any sequence of characters that contains `p` followed by exactly one character, followed by a `t`. As long as this is run in case-sensitive mode, this will not match `Pot`.

Of course, if you don't need to match the entire string (just some part of it), this is even simpler:

```
p.t
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest regex I can write:

```
^.*p.t\w*
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the much simpler one!!

```
 ^.*p[a-z  ?]t(\w+)?
```